# solutions for creating the servermodel for titanium apps

Tags: cloud, titanium

I am interested in developing an app for Android and iOS using Titanium that stores the data on a server. The data should also be available for a web client running in the browser. Any changes made to the data in the browser should trigger push notification on the phone.

What should I use for easily implementing the server functionality for this work? Is AppEngine suitable for this?

I want to use Titanium and C# for this project, please provide me any solutions you think would mke my job easier.

Thank you,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use .NET/C#, I would look at Windows Azure for the hosting part (because it is Platform As A Service, it makes it very easy to deploy a new ASP.NET + SQL application). I would write the back-end using ASP.NET MVC because it's clean and simple, especially for writing APIs. Use JSON to serialize everything. You can look at Urban Airship for push notifications, they don't have a C# SDK but their REST API looks fairly simple.